# can't see UDP broadcast with netcat

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, netcat

I'm trying to broadcast UDP over a network.

Some details about my network.

The broadcast will be happening from 172.24.176.219

I will be listening for broadcast at 172.24.176.116

The netmask is 255.255.255.0

The broadcasting code is below:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define PORT    10001
#define MAXBUF  65536

int main(void) {
    int sock, status, buflen, sinlen;
    char buffer[MAXBUF];
    struct sockaddr_in sock_in;
    int yes = 1;

    sinlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    memset(&sock_in, 0, sinlen);
    buflen = MAXBUF;

    sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    sock_in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    sock_in.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    sock_in.sin_family = AF_INET;

    status = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sock_in, sinlen);
    printf("Bind Status = %d\n", status);

    status = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &yes, sizeof(int) );
    printf("Setsockopt Status = %d\n", status);

    inet_aton("172.24.176.255", &sock_in.sin_addr);
    sock_in.sin_port = htons(PORT + 1); // port number
    sock_in.sin_family = AF_INET;

    sprintf(buffer, "Ciao");
    while(1)
    {
        buflen = strlen(buffer);
        status = sendto(sock, buffer, buflen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sock_in, sinlen);
        printf("sendto Status = %d\n", status);
        sleep(1);
    }

    shutdown(sock, 2);
    close(sock);
}
```

Here is the `Makefile` to compile the `C` source. Name `C` source `myserver.c`

```
CFLAGS+=-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c99

TARGET=myserver

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET)
```

The netcat command I'm running to listen for UDP is

`nc -ul 172.24.176.116 10002`

The problem is that I don't see anything displayed by netcat. I sniffed the traffic with Wireshark and I do see a packet being sent to 172.24.176.255

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I tried listening on 172.24.176.255, `nc -lu 172.24.176.255 10002`, but got the following output `nc: Can't assign requested address`.

Am I missing something or netcat just can't handle UDP broadcast?

Comment: I get this: `nc: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: Sorry, extra 0 in there, that port is out of range ;) `nc -ul 0.0.0.0 10002`

Comment: I am attempting this across my network now and it appears to be working as expected.

Comment: @MattClark Doesn't work for me. Have you compiled the code and tried it across multiple devices?

Comment: Sorry, `nc` with broadcasts is working - if you see the packets in Wireshark, I expect that your C code is not the issue.

Comment: @MattClark You said you tried it. Have you actually tried it in a network environment yourself across 2 devices? I'm just wondering if there is an issue with my network. And the only way to prove it is to run the setup on a different network. Hence my question.

Comment: perhaps a firewall/ip tables issue? does it work on loopback?

Comment: @yano We have a small lab network at work. It is a bunch of instruments connected tother. All we have are a bunch of switches and nothing else. The network is not connected to the internet. No firewall. And I doubt it is a ip table issue since I'm able to talk to all other devices on the network.

Comment: @MattClark If you are going to try it on the network, I can give you a Makefile to compile my code in case you need it.

Comment: Please share the Makefile, when I get home from work I can test this on my network setup.

Comment: @MattClark Added Makefile under the C source. Name C source myserver.c for compilation. Place Makefile in the same directory as the myserver.c. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: "_I'm trying to broadcast UDP over a network._" Please don't. Based on your comments, that really isn't appropriate. You should be using multicast. If you want to sell this, understand that companies are very concerned about security, and they will test and not purchase software that indiscriminately broadcasts to _every_ device on a network, including those not interested. This is why multicast was designed. IPv6 has eliminated broadcast, and you would need to use multicast, anyway, to add IPv6 support (another must have for many companies).

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for comment. But so far this is for internal testing purposes only. We will definitely change the scheme if we this feature is needed in the final product.